# match characters in a word

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find a regular expression to find the occurence of certain sequence of characters inside a set of words..

Lets say if I have a set of words

```
["Microsoft Windows", "International Superstar", "algorithm" , "stegration stunt"]
```

I am trying to find the words in which character "`in`" has occured.. so it should return the words `"Microsoft Windows", "International Superstar"`

Ive tried `var match = /(in)/i.exec("Microsoft Windows")`
it dint do the trick.. the sequnce "in" is just an example.. it could be anyset of characters..

Comment: @lanzz I was just saying that I had mentioned it in my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
/".*in.*"/gi
```

Comment: /.*in.* /gi.exec("Microsoft Windows");
gave me the value null

Comment: @user1371896. That's becuase your string didn't  have a quotes: [Fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4zd8e/3/)

Comment: Ive found something close to what I am looking for.. http://jsfiddle.net/4zd8e/1/ but how do I alter the sequence "in" ..it could be anyset of wrds.. this fiddle only compares the words with in

Comment: is it possible to make the /".*in.*"/gi in your answer dynamic?? it doesnt have to be in all the time.. it could be any set of keywords

Comment: @user1371896. Yes, it's:`var str = "in"; var regex = new RegExp(str,"ig");`

Comment: can we make this case Insensitive??

Comment: @user1371896. yes with the `i` modifier... as I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

First define your regex,

```
var testRegex = 'in';
```

then create your regex object

```
var myRegex = new RegExp(testRegex,"g");
```

then go ahead and use it like any normal regex.

Answer (score 0):

***note:*** *it's case-sensitive.*

```
<script>

var arr = ["Microsoft Windows", "International Superstar", "algorithm" , "stegration stunt"];
var i;
var res = [];
for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {

    if(arr[i].indexOf('in') > -1){
        res.push(arr[i]);
    }
}
alert(res);
</script>
```